# Is there a way to automatically set Execute permissions for new files?

Tags: macos, automation, file-permissions

I'm using OS X 10.6.4 and am trying to set a folder to automatically enable execute permissions on new script files copied or created in a directory. I have used [Sandbox 2](http://mikey-san.net/sandbox/) to set every permission for the folder to enabled with sticky bits and the inherit flag set but I still have to manually set the execute flag using chmod for every new flag.

I've done:

```
chmod -R a+rwxs ~/scripts
```

I've done:

```
chmod 7777 ~/scripts
```

And the permissions for the folder show as:

```
drwsrwsrwt+ for the folder.
```

But if I add a new script file it's set to `-rw-r--r--+` (the default)

I looked at setting `unmask 000` in the `.profile` file but the default value for files is 666 with an unmask of 022 so that's not relevant since I would need a default value of 777 for files.

I have figure out how to use `chmod` in an AppleScript triggered by a folder action to automate this but I'm wondering if there is a simple ACL or chmod setting I'm missing.

So, is there a way to automatically set execute permission for new files? (Without using a folder action and AppleScript?)

Answer (score 2):

OK, I thought I'd give it a few days to see if there was a more sane way to do this. So, here is the AppleScript I created to automatically set any file to executable. It's not perfect though, like if you have a folder with a weird name, e.g. "Scripts, Ruby", it won't work but it's a good start for anyone wanting this functionality.

You need to copy this text to an AppleScript then copy that script file to your Folder Action Scripts directory (~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts or /Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts). Then right click on the folder you want to add the script to, choose "Folder Actions Setup..." and choose this script out of the list.

I've got a much more complicated version that does stuff like updates itself, only allows certain file types to be changed on a per folder basis, allows you to use any username and password to set permissions, and sends growl notifications but I wanted to keep it simple so the solution wasn't obfuscated by the fancy bells and whistles.

Anyway, hope this helps someone else trying to do the same thing.

```
-- Set all the files in the directory to executable
on adding folder items to currentFolder after receiving addedItems
  try
    -- Set execute permissions for each file that is copied to this directory
    repeat with anItem in addedItems
      tell application "Finder"
        try
          -- Test to see if it's a file or folder (we ignore folders)
          set fileType to type identifier of (info for anItem)
          -- It's a file so change the permissions to execute
          do shell script "/bin/chmod u+x " & (the POSIX path of anItem)
        on error
          -- It's a folder so do nothing
        end try
      end tell
    end repeat

  on error errorStr number errorNumber
    -- Let the user know there was an error
    display dialog errorStr & return & return ¬
      & "Error Number: " & errorNumber ¬
      buttons {"OK"} default button 1 ¬
      with title "Error: " giving up after 30
  end try
end adding folder items to
```